# react native maps clustering

Tags: react-native, maps, markerclusterer, react-native-maps

I want to integrate maps in my react-native app, I am using the “react-native-maps” library for that
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps
I want to use clustering but I am unable to find proper documentations related to that.
Please help me to find documentation of how to integrate maps with clustering and also tell which library is best for the implementation of clustering for both platforms, iOS and Android.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `mapbox/supercluster` [repo](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster), and [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/i-tu/05e79737adfe36935ec869125a686f82) showing how to implements supercluster to React Native. It's initially developed for browser/node applications but you can still simply `npm install` and use it (javascript is javascript everywhere).  Add the clustered markers into your MapView (originally shared [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/pull/137#issuecomment-274432642)):

```
<MapView ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }}>
  { this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
    return (
      <MapView.Marker 
        coordinate={{ latitude: marker.geometry.coordinates[1], longitude: marker.geometry.coordinates[0] }}
        onPress={() => this.markerPressed(marker)}>
        <Marker model={place} active={this.isSelected(place)} />
      </MapView.Marker>
    );
  })}
</MapView>
```

**Warning** from an [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/213) of `react-native-maps`:

> The major issue is performance, if you need to display hundreds or
>   thousands of markers you're gonna have to optimize the hell out of it,
>   and this is where it gets really hard.

`react-native-maps` also have an active **conflicting** [PR](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/pull/137) which solves this issue **both in Android and iOS** natively, but it waits for a merge. However, you can manually implement it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [react-native-maps-super-cluster](https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-maps-super-cluster). This module wraps [AirBnB's react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) and uses [MapBox's SuperCluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) as clustering engine. This module is super easy to use.

#### Demo

[image]

There is one more library for clustering [react-native-map-clustering](https://github.com/venits/react-native-map-clustering).

Answer (score 1):

yarn add react-native-map-clustering

```
import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapView from "react-native-map-clustering";


    const INITIAL_REGION = {
      latitude: 52.5,
      longitude: 19.2,
      latitudeDelta: 8.5,
      longitudeDelta: 8.5,
    };
    
    const App = () => (
      <MapView initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.4, longitude: 18.7 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.1, longitude: 18.4 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.6, longitude: 18.3 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 51.6, longitude: 18.0 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 53.1, longitude: 18.8 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.9, longitude: 19.4 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.2, longitude: 21 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.4, longitude: 21 }} />
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 51.8, longitude: 20 }} />
      </MapView>
    );
```

[image: resulting output]

Answer (score 0):

How does this work with callouts?
Using this code gives me an error: Element type is invalid: expected a string...

```
<Marker>
    <MapView.Callout tooltip>
        <Text>Test Text</Text>
    </MapView.Callout>                    
</Marker>
```