# clustring react-native-maps in react native map

Tags: google-maps, react-native-maps

I tried react native map clustering with super cluster and react-native-maps(airbnb) by using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815649/react-native-maps-clustering) which show poor performance for more nodes, to improve this where to start either airbnb java code or super cluster.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best clustering package I have found, performance is awesome and it has pretty good docs: https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-maps-super-cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, using supercluster, and here an example !

https://github.com/warka0/react-native-cluster-example